# cant connect to pptpd vpn

Tags: vpn, pptp, pptpd

I am using Centos 7 with firewalld enabled on my server and currently i am not able to connect to my pptpd vpn

---

### Logs

```
Dec 26 23:34:39  pptpd[28944]: CTRL: Client 39.55.196.181 control connection started
Dec 26 23:34:39   pptpd[28944]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Dec 26 23:34:39   pppd[28945]: Plugin /usr/lib64/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
Dec 26 23:34:39   pppd[28945]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Dec 26 23:34:39   pppd[28945]: Using interface ppp0
Dec 26 23:34:39    pppd[28945]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/5
Dec 26 23:35:09   pppd[28945]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Dec 26 23:35:09   pppd[28945]: Connection terminated.
Dec 26 23:35:09   pppd[28945]: Modem hangup
Dec 26 23:35:09   pppd[28945]: Exit.
Dec 26 23:35:09   pptpd[28944]: GRE: read(fd=6,buffer=7f6470314480,len=8196) 
from PTY failed: status = -1 error = Input/output error, usually caused by unexpected termination of pppd, check option syntax and pppd logs
Dec 26 23:35:09   pptpd[28944]: CTRL: PTY read or GRE write failed (pty,gre)=(6,7)
Dec 26 23:35:09   pptpd[28944]: CTRL: Client 39.55.196.181 control connection finished
```

Firewalld has the following port enabled
1723/tcp

My options.pptpd is as follows

```
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
proxyarp
lock
novj
novjccomp
nologfd
```

Please can anyone let me know where am I doing wrong 
is there anything else that i should enable in firewalld

Thanks

Comment: This might help: http://windowsitpro.com/networking/which-ports-do-you-need-open-firewall-allow-pptp-and-l2tp-over-ipsec-vpn-tunnels. Would also check this out if you havent, it shows the error you are getting if you look at section 4 in Troubleshooting: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-establish-pptp-vpn-client-connection-on-centos-rhel-7-linux

Answer (score 1):

Thanks but the issue was resolved as firewalld was blocking the local and remoteip configured in pptp.conf

Issue was resolved by the following command 
firewall-cmd --add-source=xx.xx.xx.x/24

Thank You